# Unable to mock a static property of a single ton class

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, moq

ObjectData which contains the singleton property:

```
public class ObjectData
{
    public static IObjectData singleTon 
    {
        get 
        {
            // code for singleton
            return new ObjectData();
        }
    }

    public virtual T CreateObject<t>()
    {
         return //single object of T ;
    }
}
```

Singleton helper which sends a type for creating an object:

```
public static class SingletonHelper 
{
    public static Model myModel
    {
        get { return ObjectData.singleTon.CreateObject<Model>(); }
    }

   
} 

     // Model which contain a property of folderName
   

     public class Model {
       public string folderName {get;set;}
    }

    // pathCalculate for which I am going to write unit test
   public class pathCalculate {
        public string myFolderName 
        {
          get { return SingletonHelper.myModel.folderName }
        }

   }
    
// I have tried 

// Assign
Mock<IObjectData> objectData = new Mock<IObjectData>();
Mock<Model> model = new Mock<Model>();
model.Setup(m => m.folderName).Returns("my expected folder Name");
objectData.Setup(m => m.CreateObject<Model>()).Returns(model.Object);

//Act
pathCalculate cl = new pathCalculate();

//Assert
Assert.AreEqual("my expected folder Name", cl.myFolderName);
```

In the `Assert` part, I get an error

> myFolderName** value Null

I believe using this code there is some problem while mocking the `CreateObject` function.

Comment: Is the property named "folderName" or "myFolderName"? What is "pathCalculate"?

Comment: @KlausGütter , Actually **folderName** is a property of "Model" class EX:-    public class Model { public string folderName{get;set;} }  and pathCalculate is a class that i am going to write a unit test for and this class contain a property which is public string myFolderName 
    {
        get { return SingletonHelper.myModel.folderName }
    }

Comment: This is not going to work. `SingletonHelper.myModel` will always return an object of class `ObjectData`, not your `Mock<IObjectData>`. You could try making the singleton instance settable from outside (i.e. from the unit test).

Comment: @KlausGütter , since ```SingletonHelper``` is static class so we can not create a Mock object of it, so could you please help me to achieve ```SingletonHelper``` instance settable.

Comment: Is `public static IObjectData singleTon { get; set; } possible?

Comment: @KlausGütter yes it is possible. could you please help me how can I fix this.

Comment: `ObjectData.singleTon = objectData.Object;`

Comment: Mock<IObjectData> objectData = new Mock<IObjectData>();
Mock<Model> model = new Mock<Model>();
model.Setup(m => m.folderName).Returns("my expected folder Name");
objectData.Setup(m => m.CreateObject<Model>()).Returns(model.Object);